# Why REST API calls made from angular 12 application showing status cancelled in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core-3.1, angular12

I have the following code developed using Angular 12 which calls a REST API developed using asp.net core 3.1:

```
this.testService.testmethod(up.Id)
                    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
                    .subscribe((response) => {});
```

On testing the above code using chrome browser (Version 113.0.5672.129) , I am seeing REST API calls getting automatically cancelled.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue

Comment: If you remove the pipe(takewhile...) temporarily, does it still cancel?